# Unity 3D - Camera follow behind main character + offset

Tags: unity-game-engine, offset

I use the attached c#  script to control the camera.

**Mouse scroll (pulley/roller/wheel)**: Zooming in and out of the main character

**Up Arrow (or W key) and Down Arrow (or X key)**: Raise and Lower the camera

**Right arrow (or D key) and Left arrow (or A key)**: Rotate the camera around the main character

I try to get the camera to follow the back of the main character, and add it the offset that player defined by using mouse and arrows.

This line correctly moves the camera according to the input from the mouse and arrows:

```cs
transform.position = target.position + offset * currentZoom;
```

This line correctly moves the camera so that it will follow the back of the main character:

```cs
transform.position = target.position - target.forward + Vector3.up;
```

But each of them works correctly only if the other is canceled. If I try to merge them into one line, like:

```cs
transform.position = target.position - target.forward + Vector3.up + offset * currentZoom;
```

then the camera doesn't move properly:

1. Using the left and right arrows moves the camera around the main
   character in ellipse/oval shape instead of in a circle
2. When the character moves, the offsset set by the right and left
   arrows isn't saved but the camera returns to being exactly behind
   the back of the main character

What do I need to do to combine the two lines so that camera does move properly?

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(10f, 6f, 0f); 
    public float RotationX = .5f;
    public float rightLeftSpeed = 5f;

    public float currentZoom = .13f;
    public float minZoom = .1f;
    public float maxZoom = 1f;
    public float speedZoom = .1f;

    public float currentHeight = 6f;
    public float minHeight = 0f;
    public float maxHeight = 10f;
    public float speedHeight = 1f;

    void Update()
    {
        currentZoom -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * speedZoom;
        currentZoom = Mathf.Clamp(currentZoom, minZoom, maxZoom);

        currentHeight += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speedHeight * Time.deltaTime;
        currentHeight = Mathf.Clamp(currentHeight, minHeight, maxHeight);
        offset.y = currentHeight;

        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rightLeftSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {

        transform.position = target.position + offset * currentZoom;
        transform.position = target.position - target.forward + Vector3.up;
        transform.LookAt(target.position + Vector3.up * RotationX);
    }
}
```

Comment: as a general rule, *never* use LateUpdate.  you'll never achieve your goal if you are messing in LateUpdate.  Suggest as a first step, start over but don't use LateUpdate for any reason

Comment: @Fattie What? Why can't they use LateUpdate?

Comment: I also join to the question. On the official Unity website documentation it says: "camera should always be implemented in LateUpdate".
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html

Comment: I've used late update without issue for years. It is literally just an update that happens later in the execution order. Camera stuff is great to put in late update cause it ensures the object it is following is in its final position for the frame before moving the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and adjusted it til it worked like you were trying to have it work. Instead of using offset, I used an angle. Then after setting the position, I rotate around the object by that angle. I set the height as part of setting the position. Lastly, I multiplied the target.forward by currentZoom to make it the distance the camera is from the object. I also adjusted the default values since these changes would make it really close otherwise. I'm pretty sure there are ways to simplify this a bit, but this works!

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Transform target;
    public float angle;
    public float RotationX = .5f;
    public float rightLeftSpeed = 5f;

    public float currentZoom = 5f;
    public float minZoom = 2f;
    public float maxZoom = 8f;
    public float speedZoom = .5f;

    public float currentHeight = 6f;
    public float minHeight = 3f;
    public float maxHeight = 7f;
    public float speedHeight = 1f;

    void Update() {
        currentZoom -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * speedZoom * Time.deltaTime * 60f;
        currentZoom = Mathf.Clamp(currentZoom, minZoom, maxZoom);
        currentHeight += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speedHeight * Time.deltaTime * 60f;
        currentHeight = Mathf.Clamp(currentHeight, minHeight, maxHeight);
        angle -= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rightLeftSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 60f;
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        var newPosition = target.position - (target.forward * currentZoom) + Vector3.up;
        newPosition.y = target.position.y + currentHeight;
        transform.position = newPosition;
        transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, angle);
        transform.LookAt(target.position + Vector3.up * RotationX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. I didn't explain the problem correctly. I updated the explanation in question. When I merge these two lines, the camera doesn't move properly. – יצחק שליסל 8 mins ago

Comment: Updated my answer. Unsure about why offset is being reset though. If you turn the character do you want the camera to be staring at the same part of the character or do you want the camera to stay in position so that you're watching the character turn?

Comment: I tried the code you wrote. This causes the camera to rotate in a circle, but not around the character.

I want that the arrows will rotate the camera around the character. If you move/turn the character, the camera also will move, but be at the same offset and follow at the same part of the character.

(The character moves in a different way, by a left mouse click on target point, and NavMeshAgent).

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and just made a test project and figured out a way to do it that had no issues. I think your issue with the offset resetting might be that you're setting the angle axis every frame and if horizontal input is 0, then it's moving back to 0 if you're not pressing anything. I've updated my answer with the code that works.

Comment: Both explanation and solution are great. You are a genius! Thanks 

Comment: What is the purpose of Vector3.up and Time.deltaTime*60f ?

Comment: Is it also a correct way to write the code like this?

`transform.position = new Vector3(
                                    (target.position - target.forward * zoomCurrent).x,
                                   target.position.y + heightCurrent,
                                    (target.position - target.forward * zoomCurrent).z
);`

Comment: Seems like it would work fine, just not quite as easy to understand at a glance what it does. I'm not sure which Vector3.up you're asking about specifically. As for time.deltaTime * 60f, delta time just makes it correct regardless of fps. And multiplying it by 60 just means the variable will represent units per second.